# correct way to model in Rails 3 / ActiveRecord - compound foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a set of locations which have a relationship to a global_identificiation table which has id, arc_id (the object_id) and arc_type (the object_type) (ie a compound foreign key). How would I set up the association so that this global information is eagerly loaded on each find of Location? such that:

```
@l=Location.find(23)

@l['id']=23
@l['name']='some place'
@l['global_info']['id']=145
@l['global_info']['arc_id']=23
@l['global_info']['arc_type']='Location'
```

Right now, for saving, I just do an after_save callback which is how it gets into database but don't have any other associations with it.

thx for any help

edit:
perhaps this could just be done as an after_find on the classes that need it?

Answer (score 0):

Either use after_find, or just create a method in your model to call, then just pass in the data as params.

Or better yet make a module that all your location based classes can include, then this module can define all sorts of location based methods.

```
 module Locations
    def find_with_data(id)
        x = Location.find(id)
        x['id']=id
        x['name']='some place' #you could pass this in params
        x
    end
  end

 class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Locations
 end
```

then call

```
 new_loc = Location.new
 new_loc.find_with_data(35)
```